# Ask sqlite3 to perform query optimization after parameter replacement

Tags: python, sqlite

I just traced back performance issues to query optimization in sqlite3 (I'm using the Python interface but I'm not sure it's relevant, the problem is probably about the sqlite API).

I describe such an example below.

My table looks like this with millions of records:

```sql
CREATE TABLE articles (
  id integer primary key,
  title text,
)
CREATE TABLE "tags"  (
  tag text,
  article_id integer not null,
  foreign key(article_id) references articles(id),
)
```

Here is the request I want to run:

```sql
SELECT tag                                                                            
FROM "tags" AS t1                                                             
INNER JOIN                                                                                
    (                                                                                      
    SELECT id                                                                              
    FROM "articles"                                                                    
    LIMIT (?)                                                                            
    ) t2                                                                                   
ON t1.article_id = t2.id
```

I observed that if the limit parameter is hardcoded, the query is way faster (0.01s vs 15s).

Using `set_trace_callback`, I saw that the query was exactly the same.

However, `explain` didn't give the same result.

I concluded that the SQLite query optimizer runs **before** parameter replacement.

Indeed, if I modify the query to be

```
SELECT t1.tag FROM
    (
    SELECT id
    FROM "articles"
    LIMIT (?)
    ) as t2 CROSS JOIN
    "tags" as t1
WHERE 
    t1.article_id = t2.id
```

it works with the same speed as hardcoded limit, as CROSS JOIN allows to control the order of the for loops ([link](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#manual_control_of_query_plans_using_cross_join)).

Thus, I conclude that the query optimizer does not run the nested loop in the same order.

In this toy example, there is an obvious order that is better. However, in other cases, I might want the query optimizer to run **after** parameter replacement.

Is there a way to do it while still using the safe methods that prevent SQL injection?

The trivial solution would be to validate that limits are integers and use simple string replacement.

Comment: Could you share the schema for these two tables to make this more easily reproducable?

Comment: (A quick attempt at a repro, where my schema and data quantities may well be way wrong, seems to say that using a placeholder/parameter is not that much slower than hard-coding the limit.)

Comment: My database is 20GB heavy :) Thus the iteration order really makes sense

Comment: Can you still paste in the related schema and index definitions?

Comment: I made it up from my example that was more complicated but sure

Comment: How many tags do you have per article, on an average? With a 1.6 gigabyte database with 1M articles and 7M tags (equally distributed) the xjoin query runs at 0.02 RPS and the others skip along happily at 22k RPS...

Comment: (Sorry, 10M and 70M. Order of magnitude here or there...)

Comment: What is a xjoin query?

Comment: "x" for cross. The cross join query you had.